# Erro na criação de FK

Tags: mysql, chave-estrangeira

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.

Executing:
ALTER TABLE `prouni`.`ies` 
ADD INDEX `local_idx` (`local` ASC) VISIBLE;
;

ALTER TABLE `prouni`.`ies`

ADD CONSTRAINT `local`
  FOREIGN KEY (`local`)
  REFERENCES `prouni`.`local` (`idlocal`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `prouni`.`ies` 
ADD INDEX `local_idx` (`local` ASC) VISIBLE

Comment: MariaDB não suporta atributo de visibilidade em índices.  Retire a palavra chave `VISIBLE`

Comment: Valeuuu <3 Deu certo!